# How do I get each frame from the camera when it is recording video in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, camera

I am working on a telepresence app that uses a Windows Phone 8 device to beam images back to a desktop/tablet PC.  I have found several samples that show how to record video, even save it to a file, but not one that shows me how to get each frame from the camera as it's streamed.  I saw a sample that used a FileSink object to save video to storage, but nothing similar for getting each frame as it is generated.  I also don't see an event in the camera object that is fired whenever a new bitmap/frame is generated.  There is an event like that for taking a picture, but picture taking is very slow and isn't usable for streaming video.

How can I get each frame as it is generated by the camera when in video recording mode?  I need this of course so I can send each frame over the socket link I have with the desktop/tablet PC.

Comment: The windows.media.capture APIs may give you something to work with.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @dav1dsm1th That's only for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: The second link is for Windows Phone 8 - the first link was included by mistake...  sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PhotoCaptureDevice or PhotoCamera you can use this

```
camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb(previewBuffer);
```

or

```
  camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(previewBuffer);
```

where `previewBuffer` is pixel array of the frame. Which you can assign to `WriteableBitmap.Pixels`

or pass raw array over the socket and assign it to image on desktop.

Comment: I am using those objects so I can try your technique.  Is there any way to get notified when a new frame is available so I don't have to poll?  With the "take photo" technique I can assign an event handler to be notified when the camera has taken a picture.  Is a similar event for each frame when in record video mode?  Then I could use your technique every time a frame came in.

Comment: for `PhotoCaptureDevice` object `PreviewFrameAvailable` event is available. Even without this you don't need to poll. Fetch whenever you want after initialization, frames will be available to you.